# How can one write a custom certificate verification logic on Amazon S3?

Tags: ssl, web-hosting, amazon-s3

From [the developer guide](http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/S3/latest/s3-dg.pdf):

> When using virtual hosted-style buckets with SSL, the SSL wild card
>   certificate only matches buckets that do not contain periods. To work
>   around this, use HTTP or write your own certificate verification
>   logic.

What I'm trying to do is host static files at S3, and access them via https://app.mysite.com/filename.jpg

It seems Virtual Hosted style URLs may not play well with SSL. Any idea what "custom certificate verification" means in this context?

[See also on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048236/amazon-s3-https-ssl-is-it-possible).

Comment: Please move to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is S3's SSL certificate:

```
subject=/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Seattle/O=Amazon.com Inc./CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com
```

The Common Name on the certificate is `*.s3.amazonaws.com`, which is not going to match `app.mysite.com`. Therefore you cannot use your own hostname (via a CNAME record) with S3 when using HTTPS (at least if you want it to validate), since S3's SSL certificate doesn't (and can't) include your hostname. You must use the `<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com` hostname instead.

Now, technically a wildcard in SSL certificate hostname only matches a single part of the hostname, so the above certificate will match `foo.s3.amazonaws.com`, but not `foo.bar.s3.amazonaws.com`. This is why the documentation says that the bucket name cannot contain periods, since `app.mysite.com.s3.amazonaws.com` will not match the certificate, but `app-mysite.s3.amazonaws.com` will.

I assume that the custom certificate validation they are referring to is if you are writing your own client which accesses S3, which is not the case here.

**Edit**: As @ceejayoz points out, you can still use path-style access for buckets with periods in the name, however, you should [use the correct region specific hostname](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html) since AWS can't select the correct endpoint when the DNS request is made.

```
https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/app.mysite.com/
```

Comment: Incidentally, if you run into this, you can always do https://s3.amazonaws.com/app.mysite.com/ instead.

Comment: @ceejayoz True, I've added that.